# Como converter uma string em objeto no JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho este código:

```html
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.14/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css">
  <title>jQueryUI 1.8.14 Autocomplete</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">


function montaAutocomplete(source) {
  
  var dados = [{ label: "Agostinho", value: "1" }];
  //DADOS: VARIÁVEL ESTÁTICA
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = dados;

  //SOURCE: VEM DO BANCO DE DADOS
  document.getElementById('resultado1').innerHTML = source;

    $("#descricao").autocomplete({
        source: dados,
        minLength: 1, //quantidade de caracteres para começar a buscar
        select: function (event, ui) {
            //evento de quando você seleciona uma opção        
            $("#descricao").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#id").val(ui.item.value);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
   
}

function busca(x){

  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "autocomplete.php?q=" + x,
    dataType:'text',
    success : function(data) {
        montaAutocomplete(data);
      }
    });

}






</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="descricao" onkeyup="busca(this.value);" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
<input type="text" name="id" id="id">
<br>
dados:<br><div id="resultado"></div>
<br>
source:<br>
<div id="resultado1"></div>
```

É uma aplicação com o recurso de autocomplete o qual comunica-se com o arquivo `autocomplete.php` que, a partir das teclas digitas pelo usuário, ele retorna o seguinte código.:

Exemplo, se o usuário digitar no input o nome `agostinho`, o autocomplete irá retornar

> [{ label: "Agostinho", value: "1" },];

Entretanto estou com dificuldades em repassar esse retorno para a função `montaAutocomplete(source)` pois, aparentemente, o javascript o interpreta como uma string comum e não como um objeto.

Veja que na imagem abaixo a variável `dados` , que é estática, é interpretada como objeto, já a variável `source` é interpretada como uma string comum.
[image: string_para_objeti]

Como posso converter esse resultado que é retornado de autocomplete para um objeto em javascript?

Answer (score 1):

A melhor solução seria **jQuery.parseJSON**

[Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('[{ label: "Agostinho", value: "1" }]');
```

exemplo como poderias usar na função **montaAutocomplete**:

```
function montaAutocomplete(source) {

  var dados = [{ label: "Agostinho", value: "1" }];
  //DADOS: VARIÁVEL ESTÁTICA
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = dados;

  // exemplo
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(source);
  //SOURCE: VEM DO BANCO DE DADOS
  //document.getElementById('resultado1').innerHTML = source;
  console.log(obj); // verifica se esta tudo ok


  $("#descricao").autocomplete({
    source: dados,
    minLength: 1, //quantidade de caracteres para começar a buscar
    select: function (event, ui) {
        //evento de quando você seleciona uma opção        
        $("#descricao").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#id").val(ui.item.value);
        event.preventDefault();
      }
  });

}
```

**ou** ainda melhor antes de chamares a função se possivel faz o parse do objeto, assim ja não tens de o fazer dentro da função:

```
var objeto = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
montaAutocomplete(objeto);
```

Answer (score -3):

Consegui resolver com um pouco de pesquisa, rs.

Caso alguém se encontre nessa situação, use da seguinte forma:

```
  var dados = eval(source);
```

A função eval () avalia ou executa um argumento.

Se o argumento for uma expressão, eval () avalia a expressão. Se o argumento for uma ou mais instruções JavaScript, eval () executa as declarações.

Comment: Você está recebendo negativos porque `eval` é perigoso e raramente deve ser usado. Para o seu caso, bastam as funcionalidades nativas do `JSON.parse`.